# Why Xcode provide Tableview if collection view already exist to perform task

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

why Xcode provide tableview if we perform same action in collectionview for development of app?

Comment: The question is quite broad and shows little research. TableViews are are a common component, used to display list data. CollectionViews are a lot more powerful and take more effort to implement.

Comment: Yes, but there are expectations and rules, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You asked why you getting downvotes and I told you. I didn't make the rules

Comment: @Scriptable ok thank you next time I will remember this things.

Answer (score 1):

- Table view  are giving the listing style out of the box for for
  displaying setting like things you don't need customize anything
- But for the collection view you will need to customize it to get
  those listing styles
- No doubt you can only work with collection view but then you will need to code more or customize it more and more for that
- So both are having their own usability

More explanation you can check  [here](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/161-uitableview-vs-uicollectionview)

Answer (score 1):

UITableview has been in iOS since the launch of the App Store. UICollectionView is a more recent addition (4-5 years old) and provides a much more flexibility. Yes UICollectionView duplicates much of the functionality of UITableView (but not all). Generally, unless there is a pressing reason to go for UITableView, use UICollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

Basically tableview are for viewing results in form of **list** but collection view are for viewing in form of **grid**.

There are many functionality in tableview that are very hard to achieve in collection view like **UITableviewAutomaticDimension**, that helps it automatically resizing cells in tableview.

Comment: `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` achieves the automatic sizing collection view cells pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the requirements. How the application flows determines which type of UI to integrate into the application.

-> UICollectionview for creating types of UIs with multiple images shown in a grid. This might be complex logic using UITableView, but with UICollectionview, it would be easy.

Tableview: show list of items in only one column.
CollectionView: show list of items in multiple columns.

You can also check this [Link](http://medium.com/@imnitpa/swift-3-uicollectionview-vs-uitableview-9909bbc0ec66)